# Vue Components Losing Image When Rerendered

Tags: vue.js

I have a sidebar component located in a view-router view component that renders several child component buttons. It renders the child components using v-for loops.

```html
<div v-for="type in this.facebookLightButtons" :key="type">
  <SidebarButton :type="type"/>
</div>

<div v-for="type in this.facebookButtons" :key="type">
  <SidebarButton :type="type"/>
</div>
```

`facebookLightButtons` is simply an array of strings containing the text of the button (which is also the name of the image source of the button). The result is the following:

[image]

The corresponding code in the SidebarButton components are:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link :to="'/' + capitalizeFirstLetter(type)" class="sidebar-button">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img class="sidebar-button-icon" :src="getImage" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>{{capitalizeFirstLetter(type)}}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

and

```js
computed: {
  getImage() {
    return require('@/assets/images/SidebarIcons/' + this.type + '.png');
  }
}
```

When I change to a new view-router view and then return to the home page where this sidebar is located, the images are all missing:

[image: Missing Images]

I am trying to figure out how to keep the images there when returning to the home page.

Things I have tried:

- Clearing and setting the image source in the SidebarButton components in the created, beforeMount, mounted, activated, deactivated, updated, and unmounted lifecycle hooks (non of which seemed to work).
- Clearing the image, waiting for 2000 milliseconds using setTimeout() and then setting the image to the correct image source
- Wrapping both the contents of the SidebarButton template as well as the v-for loop in the parent component with a `<keep-alive>` tag
- Hard coding each SidebarButton component instead of using a v-for loop

It seems like something must be missing. What can I do to ensure that these images stored locally on my computer not only show when first displayed, but also appear when the user returns to the homepage after entering a separate view-router view?

Comment: FYI, don't include the `this.` prefix within your templates. They already execute within the context of the Vue / component instance

Comment: If you inspect the missing images with the browser dev-tools, what is the problem?

Comment: I have a question about it.Why do you use "computed“ instead of method in common so that it can get the parameter "type"?

Comment: @taolu I was just experimenting with computed to see if somehow it would cause it to re-render properly.

Comment: @Phil Okay, good to know.

Comment: @Phil I inspected the missing images with the dev tools and found that the HTML for the components is identical before and after. However, I did find that `md-theme-default` is added to the main html tag (after lang). This came with a number of additional CSS rules. I found that after commenting out all my calls to the Vue Material library, I no longer have this problem.